# How to automatically disable trackpad when I am coding with vim in iTerm2?

Tags: trackpad, iterm, vi

As the touchpad is bigger now, when I am coding in vim, my thumbs occasionally touch the trackpad and thus move the cursor to somewhere else, which is extremely annoying.
How to disable trackpad automatically when I am typing, or else how to just disable trackpad in iTerm2?

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is not in anyway unique:  [photoshopCAFE YouTube review](https://youtu.be/8zqwu3YbEZM?t=50s)

There's no way to disable the trackpad unless you hook up an external mouse/trackpad (which may be your solution).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Mouse -> Scroll wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode = No

and that disabled the annoying scroll from my thumbs while in vim.